# How to access current DOM object in jQuery (improve code)

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm trying to improve my jQuery code by understand how `this` works. I made this code:

```
$('.type, #type').on('change', function() {
    selected = $(".type, #type :selected").val();
    show = selected != 0 ? true : false;
    $(".div").toggle(show);
});
```

And had some toughs about it:

- As you may see I use `.type, #type` but what if I want to write a selector that match the same value in any attributes? Ex: `class=type, id=type, name=type`, it's possible to write a selector for that case? How?
- The code right now works, but I want to use `this` whenever it's possible, if I use the selector `.type, #type` then I'll have a DOM object with all the properties for that object, right? Then how to access object properties or methods? Ex: `selected = $(".type, #type :selected").val();` get in `selected` the value for selected option I tried this `selected = $(this + " :selected").val();` but don't work

Any advices or help? Any improve you'll made to my code?

Comment: `->` http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at jQuery's selector section, without specifying all the element you want, you can't just "select" them magically. Keep in mind you can do stuff like:

```
$('input[type="text"]')
```

In your second question, you can use:

```
$(this).find('option:selected').val()
```

<s>And, as a side note, check out [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)</s>

Comment: What is your advise regarding `toggle`?

Comment: Whoops. Didn't realise you were already using toggle. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your two questions:

1) The only way to do this by creating a variable and using that:

```
var name = 'type';
$('.' + name + ', #' + name).on(...)
```

2) You can use `this` like so:

```
$('.type, #type').on('change', function() {
    selected = $(this).val();
    show = selected != 0 ? true : false;
    $(".div").toggle(show);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To access via ids and classes, you already have done,

```
.type is class="type"
#type is id="type"
```

The next one,

```
name="type"
```

is a little different, Depending on what you are actually looking for, you can use a find() method, but usually, you'll know a selector type, and then you can use the

```
$(selector).attr('name')
```

property of it.

Using 'this' in the :selected construct doesn't work, with out some variable hackery, and I'd suggest avoiding it, simply reprinting the entire statement out